# Chebyshev / Chebychev but with additional deterministic sequence

Tags: statistics, inequality, convergence-divergence

We have $X_n$ with $E(X_n) = \mu_n$, $Var(X_n) = \sigma^2$ and

$\mu_n\to \mu$; $\sigma^2 \to 0$   as   $n\to \infty$.

Chebyshev states: $P(|X_n - \mu_n|\geq c ) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{c^2}$.

But what about $P(|X_n - \mu|\geq c )$ ?

I tried with $P(|X_n - \mu_n|\geq c ) = P(|X_n - \mu + \mu - \mu_n|\geq c ) \leq P(|X_n - \mu| + |\mu - \mu_n|\geq c )$

but that does not help me.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: If $|\mu - \mu_n| < c$ then I would have thought that by considering each tail you could have $P(|X_n - \mu|\geq c ) \le \dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2 + (c +\mu- \mu_n )^2} + \dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2 + (c +\mu_n- \mu )^2}$ and possibly something tighter

Comment: thank you for the answer, could you explain a bit more in detail how you got the right hand side?

Comment: applying a one-sided version of Chebyshev's inequality twice